# Query timeout expired in django-mssql when executing custom SQL directly

Tags: sql, django, django-mssql

I am querying a view which will return huge data and takes more than 1 minute to complete.

I am executing the query with django.db.connection.cursor() since this is not my default db. After 30 seconds I am getting an exception 'Query timeout expired'. I think 30 seconds is the default timeout of django-mssql. Is there a way to increase timeout period or is there any other way.

Can't work on SQL query because it is implemented by another party. Only a view is exposed.

`str(Exception)` is "(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server', u'Query timeout expired', None, 0, -2147217871), None)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can adjust the COMMAND_TIMEOUT in the database config, in your django settings file. Example of using COMMAND_TIMEOUT:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'NAME': DATABASE_NAME,
    'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
    'HOST': DATABASE_HOST,
    'USER': DATABASE_USER,
    'PASSWORD': DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    'COMMAND_TIMEOUT': DATABASE_COMMAND_TIMEOUT,
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked. What exactly is  DATABASE_COMMAND_TIMEOUT ? Seconds, milliseconds ?
Also can we set it as no timeout ? @AdrianGhiuta

Comment: DATABASE_COMMAND_TIMEOUT is seconds. Afaik, a value for it is required (it will default to 30s otherwise), it cannot be set to no timeout.

Comment: It can be set to Zero, which means no timeout

Comment: Thanks this was super helpful.